# if: Expression Syntax - in C Shell script

Tags: csh

I know that there are a lot of questions about `if: Expression Syntax`, but, please, I ask for help.

Here is my statement:

```
if !(${MY_ROOT}/dir/dir/bin/file --version >&/dev/nul) then
   #TODO 
if !(which file >/dev/null 2>&1) then
   #TODO
```

What's wrong with that? As for paths and file, everything is okay. Just mistake in statement, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the commands in `'` to use the result in the condition.

You're missing the `endif` in both statements.

```
if !(`${MY_ROOT}/dir/dir/bin/file --version >&/dev/nul`) then
   #TODO 
endif
if !(`which file >/dev/null 2>&1`) then
   #TODO
endif
```

[As per the documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#if_statement)