# C Shell: "if: Expression Syntax"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh, tcsh

I have to write a C Shell script for work, and I have no idea why my if statement is apparently malformed. I have something like this:

```
    #!/bin/csh -f
    
    foreach line("`cat file.txt`")
    
        set curr_line = `echo $line | awk '{print substr($0, 1, 20)}'`
    
        if ($curr_line == "string of text...") then
            echo "Success!"
        endif
     end
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, I just needed quotes around the string variable:

```
if ("$curr_line" == "string of text...") then
            echo "Success!"
        endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Same question asked in another post:
[if: Expression Syntax - in C Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002564/if-expression-syntax-in-c-shell-script)

> You need to wrap the commands in ' to use the result in the condition.

So this is what it should be:

```
if (`$curr_line == "string of text..."`) then
    echo "Success!"
endif
```

Comment: When I try this, the script runs, but then it tries to run each line of text as if it were a command, and I get [first line of text]: Command not found